# Is the word “flatulence” ridiculous sounding?

Tags: slang, formality, euphemisms

I ask because there is a small disagreement over the terminology that was used in the following (original) Travel.SE [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/118383/my-seatmate-has-digestive-problems-causing-unpleasant-smell-what-ought-the-cabi)

> My seatmate farts like rotten eggs. What ought the cabin crew do?

The discussion, as far as I'm concerned, is over. The "new" and approved title *“My seatmate has digestive problems causing unpleasant smell. What ought the cabin crew do?*” should remain.

***BUT* I am interested** in knowing if other native speakers agree with the following assertions

> "Flatulence" just comes off as comic/ridiculous, it's worse than "fart"

and [emphasis in bold not mine]

> The phrase "recurrent flatulence" is **really ridiculous** - **it sounds comic**. It's admirable to want to change it to a neutral word in native English, but you definitely don't want "recurrent flatulence"! It's almost like the edit is **making fun of** the OP

The offending edit, suggested by me, was

> My co-passenger has recurrent flatulence. What ought the cabin crew do?

1. Are the observations made by the American speaker valid? Would visitors snigger at the word "[flatulence](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/flatulence)"?
2. Would they think that the proposed edit was making fun of the OP? Why?

I am honestly interested in hearing if the term "flatulence" causes hilarity among Americans, Britons, and Australians. I've always assumed that it was a formal, albeit slightly stuffy, alternative to “fart”.

Comment: I quite like this quote from Kurt Vonnegut: [*I tell you, we are here on Earth to fart around, and don't let anybody tell you different.*](https://www.psychologytoday.com/gb/blog/one-among-many/201311/flatus-interruptus) Finding flatulence funny is one of relatively few universal human characteristics, I believe. I'm no doctor, but I can imagine it could be a serious (i.e. - *not* funny) situation on an aircraft, where low cabin pressure might really exacerbate a passenger's discomfort.

Comment: @FumbleFingers but the author uses the word "fart"... You cannot say "We are here on Earth to flatulent around" Well, I suppose you can. But is the term "comical" per se? And yes, I am asking for native speakers to voice their opinions, but that **doesn't mean supporting evidence cannot be supplied as well.**

Comment: I don't think there's any dictionary-acknowledged ***verb*** form etymologically cognate with ***flatulence*** (a few inventive writers have used [***flatulate***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+flatulated%22), but it's never caught on). Whatever - I don't really see how anyone could completely decouple their (individual) reaction to the *words* from their (shared) reaction to the referent subject matter. Remember that some people are quite childish though - they might think ***flatulence*** is funny partly because it's got more than two syllables.

Comment: Short answer: no. It's a perfectly ordinary term. No more ridiculous than "gastric reflux" or "diarrhoea" (and easier to spell than the latter). I'm comfortable with good anglo saxon words like fart and shit, but my elderly relatives would not be.

Comment: English has entertained a number of euphemisms for _flatulence_ —including "breaking wind," "blowing [one's] nose," "passing gas," "making a trumpet of [one's] ass," and "pooping" (according to Nathan Bailey's _English Dictionary_  the verb _poop_ means "to break Wind backwards softly"). It seems to me that _flatulence_ is the most scientifically reputable and, therefore, neutral term to use—neither rude/coarse nor excessively diffident or mannered. A person who denounces _flatulence_ as "ridiculous" is, as far as I can see, turning a personal reaction into a cultural critique.

Comment: I find *digestive problems causing unpleasant smell* to be more ridiculous than either *fart* or *flatulence*. Not only is it awkward and imprecise but it's ungrammatical. As for the question, if I had to rate the two words on some kind of political correctness scale, I'd say that *flatulence* is more acceptable.

Comment: @JasonBassford thanks for the vote of confidence. But this was said to me by an American user, and he was very, very insistent about it. How can I know if his viewpoint was [condivisible](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174004/how-to-say-succinctly-an-opinion-which-is-shareable-and-agreed-upon-by-many) if I don't ask?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm Canadian (so at least North American) and the assertion—that it's "ridiculous"—doesn't sound at all correct to me . . .

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea why some people would think that the use of the word flatulence was ridiculous. It is a more formal word than fart. It is the [standard medical term](https://www.healthline.com/symptom/flatulence):

> flatulence is a medical term for releasing gas from the digestive system through the anus

Maybe they think it sounds so formal that it is a bit like a joke, like saying "he uses the sinister member when composing a written document" rather than "he writes with his left hand".

Answer (score 0):

**flatulence**  [vocab.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/flatulence)

> 1. a state of excessive gas in the alimentary canal
>
> Synonyms:
>       flatulency, gas
>
> Type of:
>       physical condition, physiological condition, physiological state
>       the condition or state of the body or bodily functions

[why is flatulence funny](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-flatulence-funny-Is-there-an-evolutionary-explanation)

> So farts are funny because people are so precious about them, ohhh the
>   horror!, because they sound funny, because they smell bad, because
>   they embarrass people, and because whoever you are, high or low, that
>   asshole can always bring you back to earth, it's the great leveler.

and [The Atlantic Magazine](https://www.theatlantic.com/entertainment/archive/2014/11/the-politics-of-the-poop-joke/382970/)

Your questions:

> Are the observations made by the American speaker valid? Would
>   visitors snigger at the word "flatulence"?

The context of flatulence in AmE is usually more formal. A **Flatus** and **flatulence** IMHO would not be sniggered at.

> Would they think that the proposed edit was making fun of the OP? Why?

No, especially in this context. There by the grace of God, we could all be 'guilty'.

Comment: I know *why* people find the term "fart" to be funny. My question is about the term *flatulence*, is that too comical? As an American, it's on your profile page, do *you* find the word *ridiculous* or *comical*?

Comment: no i would not ... so edited